# jsf navigation between tabs during textfield validation

Tags: java, jsp, jsf

I'm quite new to JSF and I have run into a strange issue, not sure how to solve it.

I have multiple tabs in a screen and in one of the tab i have text fields, drop downs etc. 
All the text fields and drop downs have **required="true"** set.

Because of this validation, when I try to navigate to another tab without entering or selecting a value, I'm not able to navigate and it displays the validation message (**value is required**).

But I have a save button in the tab, the validation should trigger only when I click the save button, not during the Tab switch/navigation. Between the validation works when I click the save button, all I want is the validation should not get triggered when I switch over to a different tab.

This validation is not allowing me to switch over to different tabs and not
sure why this validation is triggered when I switch tabs.

Could any one please suggest a solution for my issue.

---

**Update**: here are the changes I made based on the answer of CycDemo:

```
<h:tab name="First Tab" accessKey="s">
    <h:panelGroup >
    <h:dataTable id="firstTable" styleClass="dataTableEx" headerClass="headerClass"
                footerClass="footerClass" rowClasses="rowClass1,rowClass2"
                columnClasses="columnClass1" value="#{clientProductCRUDBean.model}"
                var="item" border="1"  cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" >

                <!-- this for the incoming originator type dropdown field -->

                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="firstDropDown" />
                    </f:facet>
                     <h:selectOneMenu id="firstDropDown"  
                                required="true" requiredMessage="required field" immediate="true" >
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="--Select--" itemValue="#{null}" />
                            <h:message for="firstDropDown" errorClass="generalErrorText"/>
                    </h:selectOneMenu>  
                </h:column>                                 


                <!-- this for the outgoing originator text field -->

                <h:column >
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="firstTextField"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:inputText id="firstTextField"
                    required="true" validatorMessage="Max Length 20" requiredMessage="required field" immediate="true" >
                    <f:validateLength maximum="20"/>
                    <h:message for="firstTextField" errorClass="generalErrorText"/>
                    </h:inputText>
                </h:column>

            <!-- this for the replace or randomise radio buttons text field -->

                    <!-- this for the operators selection drop down-->

                </h:dataTable>
    </h:panelGroup>

    <h:panelGroup style="padding: 1px;  margin-top: 5px;" >
                <h:commandButton id="firstSaveButton" styleClass="commandButton"  value="Save" />
                <h:commandButton id="firstSaveCancel" styleClass="commandButton" value="Cancel" immediate="true"/>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <br />
</h:tab>
```

It still invokes the validation.

Comment: I'm sorry, I work for a company and I wont be able to post the code, But I can assure that I was able to navigate to other tabs when I removed the  required="true" from the text fields and drop downs. May be I can try to come up with a simple code that replicates this issue. Thank you for showing interest.

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to `switch/navigation` without validation process, you have to use `immediate="true"` in your action component.

Let's say, You have as below.

```
<h:commandButton value="Save" />
<h:commandButton value="NextPage" immediate="true"/>
```

When you click `Save` button, validation process will be work. But, `NextPage` is clicked validation process will be overcome.

**Note**
If there are `immediate="true"` input components, even if you click `NextPage` button, the validation process will be perform for that component.

Example

```
<h:inputText id="name" value="#{...}" immediate="true" required="true">
<h:commandButton value="Save" />
<h:commandButton value="NextPage" immediate="true"/>
```

if you click `NextPage` button, the validation process of `<h:inputText id="name"...>` will be perform. You might have a question.Why they do like that?
The answer is you have to learn [`JSF Life Cycle`](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html).

Comment: Thank you, not sure whether I understood everything, but I have pasted the code with changes from your suggestion, still I'm not able to navigate to another tab without entering values in text field or selecting value from drop down.

Comment: You should **not** have added `immediate="true"` to the input components at all. See also the "note" of the answer.

Comment: @BalusC, honestly I was looking for you to come to my rescue, have seen many of your post, thank you. I'm sorry this is what I have in my input component.  <h:inputText id="firstTextField"
                    required="true" validatorMessage="Max Length 20" requiredMessage="required field" immediate="true" >

Comment: Remove `immediate="true"` from the inputs. Otherwise they will also be processed when the button with `immediate="true"` is pressed.

Comment: Its not working, this is what I have, <h:inputText id="firstTextField"
required="true" validatorMessage="Max Length 20" requiredMessage="required field" > and the command button <h:commandButton id="firstSaveButton" styleClass="commandButton"  value="Save" immediate="true"/>

Comment: @BalusC, Could you please explain why the validation is triggered when I click an another Tab. Validation should trigger only when I click the save button.

Comment: The `immediate="true"` must be set on the button which navigates to another tab, not on the save button. This is all also rather clearly explained in the answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18926/discussion-between-liketocode-and-balusc)

Answer (score 0):

Use a `<rich:tabPanel` and change the `switchType` to client. Then use `<rich:tab>`s inside it.

> `<rich:tabPanel switchType="client">`
>              `<rich:tab>`
>               .............
>              `</rich:tab>`
>   `</rich:tabPanel>`